# JAVA : ZK framework Sorting and Manual Paging

Tags: java, sorting, paging, zk

I have created manual paging in list box. Also I have sort=("auto") for each header.But this sort makes only on current page. I should make search on hole data.But on each page I am getting from database only 35 data. List box Auto paging works normal but it gets all data from data base and it makes very slow down.

Answer (score 0):

You shall implement your own ListModel to load only the required data, rather than all. [This small talk](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/July/Handling_huge_data_using_ZK) is a good reference.